# JBossAS 7.1 Install two servers

Tags: jboss, installation

I already have an installation of JBossAS 7.1, and I would like to install another one from scratch.
I extracted the JBoss-home directory to another place on my computer, when I start it, it logs deployments of applications of my old installation.

Is it possible to keep my old installation and install a new one?
I searched on the net and doc, but the only way that I found was to configure multiple instances of server in domain mode..

nb: it's intended to use in Eclipse Luna + JBossAS Tools on Windows 7 x64 pro

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find out the right configuration parameter to change and why my new instance was using the wrong place for deployments.

Here are the steps I used:

- 1/ Extract the JBossAS 7.1 directory to C:\place1\
- 2/ Edit file C:\place1\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final_2\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml

Change line

```
socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}"
```

to

```
socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:100}"
```

- 3/ Verify that you don't have an environement variable JBOSS_HOME set, if it's the case, delete it.

That's all for the moment, when I start that second JBossAS, it doesn't use the old install directory anymore.
Accessible to 8080+offset = 8080+100 = localhost:8180/